Firebase Analytics show data from more countries than my app is available in
I have a Flutter app that is currently available only in 15 countries. I'm using Firebase for analytics, but when I check the demographics, it shows users from more than 64 countries.
What could be the factors? How can I ensure the accuracy of the country-specific data in Firebase Analytics?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Maybe users can do the trick to install your app, eg:

Switch region Google Play/App Store
Find and install apk manually from outside (eg from apkpure.com...)


Firebase Analytics collects data about user's behaviour in app. Users need to open your to start measuring demographics into Firebase Analytics. It means when you publish your app to 15 countries, your users can still use it in another country (if you don't have any other policies to do so).
Example:

User downloaded an app in the USA
The same user used the app in the Brazil -> Firebase Analytics will collect Brazil as a country, because the app was used in Brazil.

